# Migration from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, migration, sql-server-2000, mysql-workbench

I need to migrate data from SQL Server 2000 to MySQL. Currently I am using MySQL workbench. Can any one tell how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for a tool MySQL has a tool called "MySQL Migration Toolkit" that can be used to migrate the data from SQL to mysql. But the first thing as mentioned above is to do a backup. The next thing to check would be whether there are any datatypes that cannot be converted?

Comment: I searched for "MySQL Migration Toolkit", but I have not got it. Can you please give me the link?

Comment: Downlaod the MySQL Gui tools http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html you can select only Mysql migration toolkit if you are not interested in other components.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, what have you tried? You can quickly migrate data from MSSQL to MySQL if they are in any of the following data file formats:

Paradox (*.db)
DBase (*.dbf)
Delimited Text (*.txt)
Excel (*.xls)
XML (*.xml)
MS Access Database (*.mdb)
ODBC

If its a one-to-one, exact same database architecture on both the new and the old servers, you might want to try using database tools meant to make this an easier process for GUI based administrators. Just go to download.com and find some software that may assist you in that migration, Navicat is a good one. The most important thing is to always BACK IT UP! BACK IT UP! BACK IT UP! Never do anything without mirroring drives and doing whatever it takes to make sure if you don't destroy any data, but if you do you'll have backup copies of it. Also how fast your machines are will be a sizable factor when it comes to migrating very large databases.

All in all you have many options to choose from, yet the most important thing is to back it up! Can't stress that enough, yeah it might seem like meaningless extra work especially on humongous database systems, but trust me, its better to be safe than sorry. Also, I always like rebooting machines prior to making database changes to them, cutting off any connection to the outside world or any processes depending or updating its data. Turning off the ODBC will do much of that for you on Windows as well, but as always better safe than sorry. Many a corruption can be avoided by simply booting the machine and having all data in memory finalized on the active database, before backing it up or appending to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [etlalchemy](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/migrating-between-databases-with-etlalchemy). It is a free, open-sourced Python tool capable of migrating between any  of the following SQL databases: PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and SQLite.

To install: `pip install etlalchemy`

To run:

```py
from etlalchemy import ETLAlchemySource, ETLAlchemyTarget
# Migrate from SQL Server onto MySQL
src = ETLAlchemySource("mssql+pyodbc://user:passwd@DSN_NAME")
tgt = ETLAlchemyTarget("mysql://user:passwd@hostname/dbname",
                          drop_database=True)
tgt.addSource(src)
tgt.migrate()
```